# How to get specific string with regular expression?

Tags: php

i have this string `Re #A4FKA-F2NW9 123test`, I want to get this number `A4FKA-F2NW9` from that string with regular expression, can anyone please help me how to get that ?

Comment: Yes correct there will be #

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex to extract that data:

```
#\K\S+
```

This will search for a `#` then all non space characters (`\S+`) until one is encountered. The `\K` makes the previous characters in the regex not returned.

https://regex101.com/r/w44Jv1/1/

You can use that with `preg_match` by adding delimiters.

```
$str = 'Re #A4FKA-F2NW9 123test';
preg_match('/#\K\S+/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

https://3v4l.org/3lOK8

You also could do this with `explode`s or `strpos` and `substr`.

Answer (score 2):

> **[substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) - Return part of a string**
>
> **[strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) - Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string**
>
> **[strrpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) -  Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string**

You can get this by using `substr`, `strrpos`, `strpos`

```
$string = "Re #A4FKA-F2NW9 123test";
$substring = substr($string, strpos($string, '#')+1, (strrpos($string, ' ')- strpos($string, '#')-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this.
Two explodes is all you need, one on `#` and one on space.

```
$str = 'Re #A4FKA-F2NW9 123test';

echo $result = explode(" ",explode("#", $str)[1])[0];
//A4FKA-F2NW9
```